Saving a file retrieved through the REST API
I am trying to save a file in NetSuite that is being retrieved from an external source. I am making a GET request from the external source to retrieve the file, but I am not sure what I need to do to save the file to a certain record. The body response provides the ref and fileName. Any help on next steps would be greatly appreciated.
I have not tried anything yet.

I am assuming you are already using a Suitelet, you will need to POST the file object to save it in the DB.
You will need to use the file and record modules at the very least.
Once you import your file object, you will need to define what file type it is, I have done this using a function to read the mime type and return the NetSuite file type name.
function convertType(mimeType) {
  if (mimeType === 'image/x-dw' || mimeType === 'application/x-autocad') {
     return file.Type.AUTOCAD
  } else if (mimeType === 'image/bmp') {
     return file.Type.BMPIMAGE
  } 

Note: there are over 20 NetSuite file types and they are not necessarily a perfect match to what the mime types can be. you can assign any file type to any mime type and still save the file. from what I can tell this is simply to make files searchable in NetSuite. One disadvantage is that there is not true catch all so if you are dynamically getting the file type, you have to pick a file type that you won't be using much and set that as the catch all so the file still saves.
once you have all of the parameters you can create the file obj
var fileObj = file.create({
   name: name,
   fileType: fileType,
   contents: contents,
   folder: folderId
});

and then save to the file you wish to save to.
var fileID = fileObj.save();

record.attach.promise({
       record: {
          type: 'file',
          id: fileID
       },
       to: {
           type: convertRecType,
           id: recId
       }
 });

file.save saves to the file cabinent, record attach attaches to the NetSuite Record you are trying to attach to.
The above code is from my Suitelet you can find more detailed information about these modules in the NS documentation
https://(your-domain).app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=chapter_4220488571.html&whence=

I am actually using a scheduled script to retrieve the file information. Am I still able to accomplish this in the scheduled script, or should I have the script call a suitelet to process?

Both the Scheduled script and the Suitelet are server side so the process should be similar the only difference I see is that instead of Post your entry point will be execute (per the NetSuite documentation.) you should be able to run as if you are posting in a Suitelet, though I have never tried this so you will have make sure you add you logs and check them in your deployment record to see what tweaks need to be made.
